# How do I create a filter feature on WordPress?

Tags: plugins, filters

I need to create a filter feature on my site so that when someone enters they may put their car details...make, model, year, mileage...etc.

Just like how amazon does it. (see photo).

[image]

The idea is to have people match the products I sell on my site to their vehicle so that they know what fits their car.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: How do you store the data you're trying to filter by? And what are you filtering? Archives? Search? Note that plugin recommendations are offtopic here

Comment: That would be my other question! I was hoping someone would point me directly to a plug-in that would carry out this function and I was hoping that the plug in would utilize the site for storage or a cloud server. I apologize for being off topic..new here.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, plugin recommendations are offtopic here, you can ask for recommendations but not on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start with this plugin or create a custom post/tax type manually:

[custom-post-type-ui](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) 
Use this to create a custom post type and associated taxonomy for the "parts".

From there you could build a form with select boxes for each taxonomy (filters) and then a submit button or trigger to get the results.  You would end up with a url something like this which would find part for that make,model and year:

/?post_type=parts&make=vw&model=golf&year=2018

There is probably a plugin that does it all, but I tend to build from scratch for max flexibility.